# pyqtgraph/numpy ScatterPlotItem big matrix ignoring masked (np.nan) values

Tags: python, numpy, pyqtgraph

Basically i have a huge matrix that i want to plot as ScatterPlotItems
I am masking it in different ways and replacing masked values with np.nan

It looks like this:

[image]

Is there a fast way to pyqtgraph.ScatterPlotItem this?

Or maybe a numpy magical way to create a [[x,y][x,y]...] from this.

ex: [[1, 2.626][1, 2.6744][2, 6744][3, 1.058]... etc]

First dimension would be the x-axis and the 2nd dimension would be the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> xs, ys = np.nonzero(np.isfinite(arr))
> ```

returns 2 arrays of indices (x, y) for the values we want to plot,

> ```
>         for i, y in enumerate(ys):
>            outYs[i] = arr[xs[i], y]
> ```

to replace the indices with values

would be nice not to have this loop, and serialize it, but it's good enough